# password_verify says everythigns a match

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a simple hash to use as a key value pare in PHP. According to the PHP best practices I should use `password_hash` and then `password_verify` to confirm they match.

However, I found that there were multiple values (in the example there are 56 matches).

```
<?php 
echo '<pre>';

$apiKey = hash('sha512', uniqid());
$apiToken = hash('sha512', uniqid());
$apiTokenHash = password_hash($apiToken, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

echo '$apiKey = ' . $apiKey . ' length = ' . strlen($apiKey) . '<br/>';
echo '$apiToken = ' . $apiToken . ' length = ' . strlen($apiToken) . '<br/>';
echo '$apiTokenHash = ' . $apiTokenHash . ' length = ' . strlen($apiTokenHash)  . '<br/>';

$verify = password_verify($apiToken, $apiTokenHash);
$style = ($verify) ? "color: green;" : '';
echo "<p style='{$style}'>({$apiToken} === {$apiTokenHash})</p>";


$count = 1;
while(strlen($apiToken) > 0) {
    $apiToken = substr($apiToken, 0, -1);
    $verify = password_verify($apiToken, $apiTokenHash);
    $style = ($verify) ? "color: green;" : '';
    echo "<p style='{$style}'>{$count} - ({$apiToken} === {$apiTokenHash})</p>";
    $count++;
}
?>
```

Does anyone understand why password_verify is accepting so many answers.

P.S. I really really tried to get this in a PHP fiddle for you but I cant figure out how to share a link to it so please dont give me a hard time about that.

Comment: You can use ideone.com to make PHP fiddles. It has a share button to let you get the link.

Comment: Thank you!!! I hate php fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) algorithm used by `password_hash()` cannot hash strings longer than 72 characters. Longer strings are truncated before being hashed.

Comment: OMG Thank you! I looked all over the php docs password_hash to see if there was a max length and didnt see it. Of course I should have looked at the length.

Comment: Don't feel too bad. It's not mentioned anywhere in the PHP documentation!

Comment: Thank you for confirming that, I always feel terrible when I ask something on the Stack and its something I missed in the docs.